# Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

For some reason its giving me the error unexpected token import on angular2. I kinda debugged it and found out the error was on app-component.ts when im importing component-mymovies... Here are my Main files...
app/app-component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {myMoviesComponent} from './component-mymovies'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-shop',
    template: 
    `
    <h1>Welcome to the shop!</h1>
    <p>Weve the following movies available</p>
    <myMovies></myMovies>
    `,
    directives :[myMoviesComponent]
})
export class myShopComponent { 


}
```

app/component-mymovies.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'myMovies',
    template: 
    `
    <ul>
        <li>Some Movie</li>
        <li>Another Movie</li>
        <li>Another Another Movie</li>
        <li> Another Another Another Movie</li>
    </ul>

    `
})
export class myMoviesComponent { 


}
```

Main.ts:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {myShopComponent} from './app-component';

bootstrap(myShopComponent);
```

and index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>


    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-shop>Loading...</my-shop>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    Evaluating https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/app/component-mymovies.js
    Error loading https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/app/component-mymovies.js as "./component-mymovies" from https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/app/app-component.js
    at eval (native)
    at SystemJSLoader.__exec (https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1395:16)
    at SystemJSLoader.<anonymous> (https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3258:18)
    at SystemJSLoader.<anonymous> (https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3526:24)
    at SystemJSLoader.<anonymous> (https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3774:26)
    at SystemJSLoader.<anonymous> (https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:4121:26)
    at SystemJSLoader.instantiate (https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:4357:28)
    at https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:333:33
    at Zone.run (https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1243:24)
    at zoneBoundFn (https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1220:26)Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publishRejection @ angular2-polyfills.js:401(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
```

And here is the place i code the thing...

https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/angular2mehul

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at your `https://angular2mehul-amanuel2.c9users.io/app/component-mymovies.js`, it appears that it's not a compiled JS file but it contains TypeScript code. That's why SystemJS isn't able to import it.

You need to have compiled code from TypeScript files into your JS files.

How do you generate the `app/component-mymovies.js` file? Using `tsc`?

Comment: I did compile my typescript files to js files.. You didnt look at the other folders

Comment: But i somehow cloned another project and fixed it here.. https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/angular2practice5-cloned#openfile-README.md   Thanks for help!

Comment: It's strange but it seems that you don't have the right content in your JS file... Could you check this?